# How to disable a right click menu item

Tags: sapb1

I am trying to disable the "copy line" item in the right click menu when pressing a matrix on a user form.

I found a way to remove this menu item with "menu.RemoveMenu("1294");" but not a way to bring it back after one use without shutting sap down.

I am looking for a way to bring back this item \ disable it
I didn't find any good answer on the "archive.sap.com" too

Thanks

Comment: I found a way to catch the menu event and turn the bubble_event to false;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the menu you can disable it when you want and enable it again when necessary. For example, you can do it in the right click event or in any event from the FormTypeEx you want. If you use the right click event code would be something similar to this.

```
    If oApplication.Forms.Item(eventInfo.FormUID).TypeEx = "MyForm" And eventInfo.BeforeAction Then
        oApplication.Menus.Item("1294").Enabled = False
    End If

    If oApplication.Forms.Item(eventInfo.FormUID).TypeEx = "MyForm" And Not eventInfo.BeforeAction Then
        oApplication.Menus.Item("1294").Enabled = True
    End If
```